# MediaExtractor - the very first result of readSampleData() is -1

Tags: android, mediaextractor

I'm trying to extract frames from a video file using Android's `MediaExtractor`, but for some reason the very first result from `readSampleData()` is -1. What am I doing wrong?

The file itself is certainly playable.

EDIT 2: [This is the link to the source code for the MediaExtractor that has this problem](http://pastebin.com/q0ekE89g)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html#readSampleData(java.nio.ByteBuffer, int) . -1 is returned if no more samples are available."What am I doing wrong" No idea since you haven't provided any code.

Answer (score 0):

-1 indicates that sample buffer is empty.Hava a look at this example,hope it helps
[Extracting pcm samples](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=22673011&ttl=How%20to%20extract%20PCM%20samples%20from%20MediaCodec%20decoder%26%2339%3Bs%20output)

Comment: That's true, but I think something's wrong when it happens at the very first `readSampleData()`.